# if .parent().hasClass then .parent().toggleClass

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Could you help me out with this?

#### Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".tile a").click(function() {
        $(this).closest("div").toggleClass("selected_tile");
        if($(this).parent().parent().hasClass("col-md-4")){
            $(this).parent().parent().toggleClass("col-md-4 col-md-12");    
        }
        if($(this).parent().parent().hasClass("col-md-6")){
            $(this).parent().parent().toggleClass("col-md-6 col-md-12");    
        }
        if($(this).parent().parent().hasClass("col-md-8")){
            $(this).parent().parent().toggleClass("col-md-8 col-md-12");    
        }
    });         
});
```

#### HTML:

```
<div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="tile">
        <a href="#">web</a>
        <div class="project_info"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I need to toggle the classes only if the parent has the class already, otherwise do nothing.

Comment: Show us your HTML code please if you can.

Comment: It could be useful if you can post a snippet of HTML code, so we can see where `<a>` and all the classes are.

Comment: What exactly do you want to do with `col-md-12`, when do you want it to appear and when to vanish? I don't think you're looking for `toggle`, especially not thrice in a row.

Comment: whenever `<a></a>` is clicked i want to change the existing `.parent().parent()` class for `col-md-12` and when it's clicked again i want to change it to its previous class

Comment: The first thing I would do is cache `$(this).parent().parent()`. No need to perform so many lookups in the DOM, and increases readability. Something like `var grandparent = $(this).parent().parent();`.

Comment: the code has it is adds the `col-md-12` but it doesn't remove it and add the initial one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need somehow to store the old class, otherwise it will get lost.

This will store the old class in "data-old-class" and toggle your new class:

JS:

```
 $(".tile a").click(function () {
     $(this).closest("div").toggleClass("selected_tile");
     //use varible!! no need to see (this).parent.parent.parent so many times XD
     var grandParent = $(this).parent().parent();
     //Check if it already has an "old class"
     if ((grandParent.attr("data-old-class"))&&grandParent.attr("data-old-class") !== '') {
         grandParent.removeClass("col-md-12").addClass(grandParent.attr("data-old-class"));
         //remove the old class (its more generic than toggle)
         grandParent.attr("data-old-class","");
     } else {
         grandParent.attr("data-old-class", grandParent.attr("class"));
         grandParent.attr("class","");
         grandParent.addClass("col-md-12");
     }
 });
```

[Fiddle](https://fiddle.jshell.net/fajh604d/3/)

Comment: this is it! was missing the `data-old-class=""` in the html
many thanks!

Comment: Yes you can use the data-old-class="" in the html, or check first in the JS that it is not empty

Answer (score 1):

Figured this one out, and there are a couple of things to address to get it working. The first step is to organize your variables and method calls a bit, for efficiency and readability, like so:

```
...
var $this = $(this),
            grandparent = $this.parent().parent(),
            cl_4 = "col-md-4", 
            cl_6 = "col-md-6", 
            cl_8 = "col-md-8",
            cl_12 = "col-md-12";
...
```

This saves us a lot of function calls and a lot of DOM lookups, which are expensive. It also saves us a lot of repetition, makes it easier to track down errors in the selection and allows us to read the code a bit better.

The second thing for it to work is to remove an argument from `.toggleClass()`, 
like so (*notice the variables instead if strings. Looks neat, no?*):

```
...
if(grandparent.hasClass(cl_4)){
    grandparent.toggleClass(cl_12);    
}
...
```

`.toggleClass` only takes one class as its argument, and from what I can read there shouldn't be a need to toggle the first class, in the example given `.col-md-6`. If there is, I'm sure you can figure out a way.

With these changes your code should work fine.

EDIT: Since all the cases (cl_4, cl_6, cl_8) seem to toggle cl_12, you could reduce the conditional to a single `if ()` with OR:s.

EDIT2: Misinterpreted the OP, and didn't see that you wanted to exchange the original class for `.col-md-12` as indicated. However, unless something odd is going on there shouldn't be any need to remove the original class (cl_4/6/8) as cl_12 should take precedence if placed after the original class.

Comment: this almost did it! just need to remove the `.col-md-6` when adding `.col-md-12` and the revert it afterwards because it doesn't take precedence. would a rename be easier to accomplish this?

Comment: Why would you need to remove .col-md-6? `class="col-md-6 col-md-12"` should for all intents and purposes be exactly the same thing as `class="col-md-12"`. 

The styles farther to the right overwrite the styles to the left : )

Comment: unfortunately it is not happening here :/
the `class="col-md-6"` is being returned as the main one

Comment: Then there is something awry somewhere else, and in that case the other solutions work; storing the old class in a data-attribute and re-applying, but I would suggest looking into why col-md-6 takes precedence even when col-md-12 is applied. 

I'm guessing that you want it to change width? If so, the width (and margin) of -12 should overwrite those of -6, when `col-md-6 col-md-12`.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to store the old class before removing it so you know what class to change back to later. You can also save `$(this).parent().parent()` in a variable to increase readability and avoid unnecessary DOM lookups as pointed out by [sxefloden](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4627215/sxefloden).

You can do it like this:

```
$(".tile a").click(function () {
    $(this).closest("div").toggleClass("selected_tile");
    var mdClass, 
        grandParent = $(this).parent().parent();

    if (grandParent.hasClass("col-md-12")) {
        mdClass = grandParent.data("previous-class");
    } else {
        mdClass = grandParent[0].className.match(/\bcol-md-\d\b/);
        grandParent.data("previous-class", mdClass);
    }

    grandParent.toggleClass(mdClass + " col-md-12");
});
```

[Fiddle](https://fiddle.jshell.net/x4bbqx6y/1/)